# Cannot find symbol id in button

Tags: java, android

Hello i am making a simple push button in android and this is my mainactivity file

```
package dk.troll.android;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

              Intent browserIntent = 
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.troll.dk"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

and this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum and so much other stuff"
    />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button - Go To Troll" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On this line `button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);` i get the error

> cannot find symbol:variable id location:class R

Since the contents of class

> r

are auto-generated,how can i fix the error?

Comment: `Import dk.troll.android.R;` in your `Activity`

Comment: check if you have errors in any of your resource files. If so fix the, clean and build

Comment: @MD,should that come at right after the package line?

Comment: @user3286430 Ya. in your import section

Comment: @MD It works but i get the warning import from the same package warning.When running it,it also says no application can handle this action.

Comment: @user3286430 There is no app that can handle your `ACTION_VIEW Intent`.BTW your older issue is not related to this.

Comment: Use this template: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57543/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default or from Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840509/why-does-the-new-adt-create-a-static-inner-class-fragment-by-default-simple-fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fist restart eclipse

then doing this :

1.import R class to your activity, Import dk.troll.android.R;

2.be sure the all recurse file have not any error then try to clean project from Project then Clean.

3.build your project